# Putting git commit and git diff into binary as strings?

Tags: c++, git

I am a graduate student and my main venue for research is software simulation. I have some C++ code that I use to generate results, but my big problem is that in order to strive for reproducibility, I want to save enough metadata in my binary so that I can go back to the exact source code that generated that binary (mostly to see if some bug I found invalidated some result I generated earlier).

In other words, when I produce a set of output files, I want the binary to dump both the git commit of the current revision as well as any outstanding changes. This would allow me (in theory) to check out that commit, apply the saved patch, and get back to the exact source code that created the binary.

I know I can do this out of band by manually saving the info or something, but in order to ensure full consistency, I'd like to just bake the information straight into the binary so that every binary will be able to be traced back to its exact source.

I'm familiar with doing things like setting a #define flag in the makefile to store something like the git commit SHA1, but I presume I need some kind of more clever way of storing the entire git diff as a string in the binary.

So I have several questions:

1. Is this a terrible idea? Is there some better approach to tracing a binary back to source?
2. What is the optimal way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

**Edit:** I guess I didn't make clear that the reason I want to save the diff is to capture any *uncommitted* changes on top of the current HEAD. I can store the hash, but if I make the mistake of using a binary with some uncommitted stuff wrapped into it, then I can't get back the correct source.

Answer (score 3):

Saving the git "id" number (hash) in your code is not a bad idea. Saving the diff is pretty pointless, as the hash (along with which branch it came from) should allow you to get back to the original code.

Just make sure your build-and-test-system is setup such that you can't use something that hasn't been committed, that way you can't have some random changes that aren't committed in the build.

Edit: 
There's a difference between testing on your machine, in a local copy of the project, and testing using the test-suite that checks EVERYTHING - this is what you use to confirm that everything works, right? Note that it doesn't REALLY matter what you test until someone else gets a copy of that code - don't let other people ever see your code until it's been committed, and don't allow the complete test-suite that saves the test results for the release notes, etc, to run if you haven't committed everything [or better yet, have a separate directory/machine, which ONLY gets fresh code from the central repo - if you do that, then you can't possibly use uncommitted code.

I have worked on several projects that work just that way - you can build in your local directory with uncommitted code, but all "official builds" are done on a different machine, code always straight from the repo, no local changes.

If you don't have two machines, perhaps having a virtual machine that "acts like a separate machine", or using simply a second directory [or different user?] that you use for the "official tests".

Actually, you could simply CHECK if there are some diffs, and then in along with your "this is the hash", if there is any differences, add an extra "-with-uncommitted-changes" or something like that. You can use `git diff --exit-code` to give you a 0 or 1 exit-code for "no changes" or "changes".

Comment: That sort of works, but I need to be able to build binaries to test changes -- and if I can build binaries, inevitably I will make the mistake of generating results with a binary that has uncommitted changes added to it.

Comment: @KarateSnowMachine: Well, then just set up your build scripts so they fail if you have uncommitted changes :-). With git, it's a good idea to make frequent commits anyway.

Comment: @KarateSnowMachine: See edit (got a bit too long to write it all as a comment - should be there in a couple of minutes if you are quick enough to see this before the edit is there).

Answer (score 2):

1. you described two ideas: only one is terrible. Just save the hash.  You can recover all other metadata, including the diff, from that
2. just store the hash (see **1**) - you state already know how to do this

Comment: Well, the point of saving the diff is to save any uncommitted changes on top of the current HEAD.

Comment: Just don't produce release builds from un-committed source. The output from `git diff` wouldn't be sufficient here anyway, because it would omit new files you hadn't added yet.

Answer (score 2):

Storing the git SHA1 id is fair enough from a technological point of view for what you want to achieve.

*Uncommitted changes?* Set up your build process to fail, if those are present.
If the build engineering is too hard/too much work, just show more discipline. :)

EDIT:
Build via a shellscript. Prior to building check for changes, `git diff --exit-code` might help.

EDIT 2:
`git help bisect` can come in handy, if you have to debug *many* revisions of code.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best answer to this is "don't do it that way". If you want repeatable builds, only build against committed changes, not with a dirty working directory. If you need to, commit experimental stuff on a side branch that you can throw away if it doesn't work out, or maybe leave it in your repository (e.g. for your use case of repeating a build), but abandon that branch and work on another new branch. If you have only specific points that you want to go back to for builds, consider dropping an appropriate tag on those specific commits.

Answer (score 1):

## [version-from-git](https://github.com/MhmRhm/version-from-git)

Bake git information into your binary.

### Objective

Consider the following C++ program:

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <format>

#include "gitversion.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::format("Build Info: {}\n{}\n{}\n{}",
        FromGit::Branch, FromGit::Tag, FromGit::Commit, FromGit::Date) <<
        std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The goal is to have a `gitversion.h` file which upon including gives us access to the branch, tag, commit and date information of the repository.

### A Recommendation

For this to work, it's recommended that the *build tree* resides outside of the *source tree* (**out of source build**.) To accomplish that using the command line:

```sh
mkdir ../build
cd ../build
```

Or if you are using the *QtCreator*, go to the *Projects* tab on the left-hand side of the IDE, choose the correct *kit*, and on the build tab select the **Shadow build**.

And if you are using the *Microsoft Visual Studio*, right-click on `CMakeLists.txt` and choose *CMake Settings for...*, then change *Build root* to something like below:

```
${projectDir}\..\build\${name}
```

If you go against this recommendation and put your build directory inside the source, every time you run the `cmake` or change project settings in your *IDE*, the `git status` may change and unwanted changes will be reflected in your binary.

### The CMakeLists File

The following is the content of the `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

project(Tutorial)

# Where we get information from the git and put it into the gitversion.h file.
include(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/gitversion.cmake)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

add_executable(Tutorial tutorial.cxx)

# Must include the build tree to get access to the gitversion.h file.
target_include_directories(Tutorial PUBLIC "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")
```

### The .cmake File

This is where the bulk of the work happens:

```
 # find_package(Git) -> finds the location of the git executable
 # git describe --always --abbrev=8 -> gives the abbreviated hash
 # git status --short -> checks for uncommitted  work
 # git describe --exact-match --tags -> gives the tag
 # git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD -> gives current branch
 # git log -n 1 --pretty=%cd --pretty=%cI -> gives the time of the last commit
find_package(Git)
execute_process(COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} describe --always --abbrev=8
                WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
                OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_COMMIT)
execute_process(COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} status --short
                WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
                OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_STATUS)
if (("${GIT_COMMIT}" STREQUAL "") OR (NOT "${GIT_STATUS}" STREQUAL ""))
    set(GIT_COMMIT "N/A")
endif()
execute_process(COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} describe --exact-match --tags
                WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
                OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_TAG
                ERROR_QUIET)
if ("${GIT_TAG}" STREQUAL "")
    set(GIT_TAG "N/A")
endif()

execute_process(COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
                WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
                OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_BRANCH)
if ("${GIT_BRANCH}" STREQUAL "")
    set(GIT_BRANCH "N/A")
endif()

execute_process(COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} log -n 1 --pretty=%cd --pretty=%cI
                WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
                OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_DATE)
if ("${GIT_DATE}" STREQUAL "")
    set(GIT_DATE "N/A")
endif()

string(STRIP "${GIT_COMMIT}" GIT_COMMIT)
string(STRIP "${GIT_TAG}" GIT_TAG)
string(STRIP "${GIT_BRANCH}" GIT_BRANCH)
string(STRIP "${GIT_DATE}" GIT_DATE)

# replaces matching variabels in gitversion.h.in file and writes it to gitversion.h
configure_file(gitversion.h.in gitversion.h)
```

### The .in File

This file is actually a `.h` file that is loaded with cmake related variables to be replaced during `cmake` execution:

```c
#pragma once
#include <string_view>
namespace FromGit
{
    const std::string_view Commit{"@GIT_COMMIT@"};
    const std::string_view Tag{"@GIT_TAG@"};
    const std::string_view Branch{"@GIT_BRANCH@"};
    const std::string_view Date{"@GIT_DATE@"};
}
```

### Last Step

Finally in our build directory run:

```sh
cmake ../Tutorial
cmake --build .
```

Make sure the `Tutorial` directory is initialized with `git`.

This solution is based on [Matt Keeter](https://www.mattkeeter.com/blog/2018-01-06-versioning/)'s work.